# Specify job step to run manually when the rest of the GitHub workflow runs automatically

Tags: github, github-actions, workflow, cicd

I have a github workflow, that runs automatically on push to branch 'dev' and I would like to have a specific step that only runs in dev and manually triggered.

I know that this is posible using GitLab, by adding "when: manual" to the step but I can't find a way of doing this on GitHub.

```
# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the main branch
  push:
    branches: [ dev ]
  #pull_request:
  #  branches: [ dev ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  triage:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/dev'
    steps:
    - uses: actions/labeler@v4
      
        
  test-workflow2:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/dev'
    steps: 
    # Runs a set of commands using the runners shell
      - name: Deploy latest
        run: |
          echo the test worked
          
  test-workflow3-manual:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/dev'
    steps: 
    # Runs a set of commands using the runners shell
      - name: Deploy latest
        run: |
          echo the test worked
    # when:
    #   manual ???
```

Thank you all in advance and have a nice week

Comment: Something like this would work: `if: ${{ github.ref_name == 'dev' && github.event_name == 'workflow_dispatch' }}`. See [`github`](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context) context for more details.

Comment: Using [this action (manual workflow approval)](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/manual-workflow-approval) could be useful in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the current branch and event should work with an `if`:

```yaml
if: ${{ github.ref_name == 'dev' && github.event_name == 'workflow_dispatch' }}
```

See [`github`](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context) context for more details.

Comment: If I got it right the PO wants to run the workflow/jobs on every push-event (and additionally when triggering manually) but after let's say build process in workflow was successful ask for manual trigger before deploying to server (or something like that).

Comment: @Luckyfella: The OP wanted to specify that a specific step should only run when the branch is `dev` and the workflow was triggered manually, and skip otherwise.